# Parsing XML Element

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to parse an xml element (`DItem` >> `Title`)
below is my code but somehow i am not getting hold of it.... any help?

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(url);
XNamespace ns = "http://sitename/items.xsd";
string topic = xdoc1.Descendants(ns + "DItem")
             .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Title"))
             .FirstOrDefault();

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">title</title> 
  <entry>
    <id>da7d3189-fd89-4d3f-901c-30eab7a3baa5</id>
    <title type="text">Swimming Pools</title>
    <summary type="text"></summary>
    <updated>2011-08-19T19:02:21Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="link" />
    <link href="link" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.namespace.xsd">
        <CatalogSource Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="organization name" />
        <Item Id="28466" CatalogUrl="url">
          <DItem xmlns:content="http://namespace.xsd" TargetUrl="http://index.html" Title="my title">
            <content:Source Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC" /> 
          </DItem>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </content>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the namespace "http://www.namespace.xsd" should (and does) work:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.namespace.xsd";
string topic = xdoc1.Descendants(ns + "DItem")
                    .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Title"))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Since `DItem` is not qualified with a namespace itself, it will use the default namespace specified as`xmlns="http://www.namespace.xsd"` on its parent element.

Comment: hmmm not sure whats wrong it returns `null`...if you look at my xml i have `<DItem xmlns:content="http://namespace.xsd"` should i provide `xmlns:content` too ?

Comment: If you want `DItem` to be in the content namespace you have to declare xmlns:content in one of its ancestors and have the name be `content:DItem`

Comment: i am lost here... the above xml i get is from third party vendor and i dont control... so i am interested in extracting the `Title` only. so what do i need to do in order to extract Title without modifying the way xml structure is?

Comment: @Abu: What I posted in my answer successfully gets the title - note the different namespace I am using